# Creating Live, Editable (Audio Waveform) Oscilloscope in Blender

Tags: python, scripting, particles, compositing-nodes, audio

I've been searching the internet for hours to find the solution to my predicament, but to no avail.

I am trying to create a virtual oscilloscope within blender, which is editable in ways similar to that of a real oscilloscope. All I really need is one (horizontal) channel that can display an audio waveform (music) with a high amount of resolution. What would also be nice (but possibly more complicated) is the ability to manually adjust the window of time that the waveform remains visible before updating, so that a signal of constant frequency remains "in phase" on the display and does not wander around.

Also, as on a real oscilloscope, I anticipate problems with "strobing," whereby the frame rate at which the oscilloscope display updates itself is not in sync with the frame rate of the blender scene. Maybe, if the oscilloscope display updates itself faster, Blender's "shutter" will have to be open long enough to capture multiple iterations of the waveform for that period of time and "ghost" them on top of one another.

Up to this point, I've been trying to increase the frame rate of blender and tweak the properties of the "bake sound to f-curves" option, but the resolution is still not satisfactorily high enough. Yes, it is possible to stretch the waveform in another program (like Audacity) and reimport (re-bake) it, but I want to avoid this as much as possible. My hope is that I can make a virtual oscilloscope display within blender to render music in real time, so that I can add a track in the VSE to hear what's happening and follow along.

Not knowing where the solution lies, I'm open to scripting, although my knowledge of Blender Python is limited, but I'll try best to follow if it ends up going in that direction. (There's plenty to learn there, so it would be a good experience for me anyway).

I've also considered creating a line of particles or vertices, whereby each would be displaced up and down on a designated axis, and which would update themselves each frame (or every subframe, according to the oscilloscope settings).

Thanks all for the help and guidance. I'm suspecting there are multiple solutions, and I'm interested in hearing whatever you all come up with!

Comment: Real time and blender often don't mix, but, I'm still interested in seeing a cool solution.

Comment: I was recently thinking about if it'd be possible to write a script that'd generate geometry or a texture from audio for such purpose.

I guess the closest thing right now would be to render the waveform with somehing like gplot, and use this as an image texture. My animating the texture mapping offset one should be able to get an oscilloscope-like animation. But it's by no means realtime or easy to pull off.